# Json Without Key to Parse in Android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I have this below Json which I'm getting from a .Net Web service:

```
[["Developer","test","developer@test.com"]]
```

I checked with jsonlint validator and It shows above json fine.

Because it is not having any `key` I don't know how to parse it in Android.
Can someone please help me how to parse this json without key.

If it had keys, I would have tried this:

```
{"first":"somevalue","last":"someothervalue"} // Json response

JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(resp); //response is the json array
String first = json_obj.getString("first");
String last = json_obj.getString("last");
String test = "Hello! " + first + " " + last;
```

Hope someone helps :)

Regards,

Praveen

**MY SOLUTION**

```
JSONArray respo = new JSONArray(resp); //resp is Json Array
respo = respo.getJSONArray(0);
String test = respo.getString(2);
test = "Your Email Address is " + test;
```

Comment: It looks like your json is an array within an array, so the first element actually came contains the whole data set. I'm not familiar with how android handles those, but but can check and post answer later (on phone atm)

Comment: So how do I parse it without `key` ?

Comment: this is NOT a JSON array in the response, it's an Array of String arrays.

Comment: Not sure of the right syntax til I get to my desk, tried [0] [0]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in Android (Java) parsing this line looks like:

```
String jsonString="[[\"Developer\",\"test\",\"developer@test.com\"]]";
try {
   JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonString);
   JSONArray jsonArray2=jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
     String valueString=jsonArray2.getString(i);
     Log.e("json", i+"="+valueString);
   }
} catch (JSONException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That was so helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Use JSONArray instead of JSONObject. Then use the getJSONArray() function to get the array inside the array. After that you can access all values with their index and getString().